# Loop through Excel sheets and `fillna(0)`

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I iterate through all the sheets in an Excel file, fillna(0) and perform a given calculation on each?

Here is my current approach but it does not function as expected:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\zj\Metabolite_Data_Summary_no_conversion.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

for key, item in df.items():
    item.fillna(0)
```

Does `item` represent each of the sheets or a DataFrame?

Comment: you're missing the `write` aspect of the operation. did you check the docs? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html

Currently the dataframe only exists in memory. Also if you do this be prepared to loose all formatting and styles from your excel sheet. As well as custom formulas.